# How to detect a directory is in use on Win32?

Tags: windows, directory, locking

I need a programmatic way to know if a directory (as opposed to a file) is in use, for example because it is open on explorer or a CMD prompt. If the directory is in use, then it cannot be deleted. The current way I have found to do that is trying to rename it, is there a less intrusive way to do this under Windows?

Comment: @Byron: That doesn't matter. The Win32 API looks the same from any language.

Comment: Why?  What do you intend to do with this information?  If you want to delete the directory then just try to delete it; it will either succeed or fail.  Also, there is nothing stopping another process from accessing the directory between the time you check if it is in use and the time you try to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't secify a language, so I am assumming c++. You can try to lock the file yourself using [LockFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365202%28VS.85%29.aspx) or LockFileEx, if it returns zero another process has the file locked already.

You can't unlock a lock if another process has it locked without terminating the process.

Comment: You assumed C++, but then you never used that assumption! :)

Comment: @Andreas, ha, I guess since the linked function is C you got me there ;)

Comment: Well, most importantly, `LockFile` is a function of the Windows API (i.e., technically an exported function of a DLL), and so it can be called from *any* programming language that is able to call functions in DLLs, which is more or less any "real" programming language. Myself I use Delphi to call the Win32 functions.